Trump violated his oath of office: How does this not make him ineligible to run?
Trump violated his oath of office: 
How does this not make him ineligible to run?


"I do solemnly swear (or affirm) that I will faithfully execute the
Office of President of the United States, and will to the best of my
ability, preserve, protect and defend the Constitution of the United
States." Presidential oath of office


@ohwilleke's answer is correct, but for future questions of this nature in the Law SE you may what to consider: what law would implicated by the behavior in question? How would it be determined that this law was broken, and who would adjudicate that result? If you have found such a law and do not understand how a particular result is consistent with it, that's also an excellent subject for a question. Lacking those specifics, it seems more like political polemic than a question about law.

SE is not an indoctrination service.

It's unclear how the tweet (image) relates to Trump allegedly breaking his oath.

@Lookingforloopholes He is calling for the constitution to be terminated violating his oath of office to "protect and defend the Constitution of the United States."

@polcott He didn't take an oath to protect and defend the constitution; he took an oath to protect and defend the constitution "to the best of his ability." I submit that he did the best he could, given his personality disorders.

@bdb484 That would be funny if not for the dire consequences.

Haha. Welcome to the capitalist legal system, where everything is a farce with dire consequences.

I agree with your premise.

Violating an oath of office does not make one ineligible to run for office, unless the person is removed from office by impeachment in a U.S. Senate judgment stating that it has that effect.
Section 3 of the 14th Amendment does has a provision barring people who have taken an office of office and then engaged in an insurrection from holding any federal, state, or local public office.
The Colorado Supreme Court ruled that Trump had engaged in an insurrection and was barred from holding office as a result. But, the U.S. Supreme Court reversed that ruling, holding, contrary to considerable legal argument in favor of the Colorado Supreme Court ruling (see also this New York Times article), that Section 3 of the 14th Amendment was not self-executing as applied to federal office, and that Congress had not adopted legislation implementing it for the Presidency.

Calling for the termination of the constitution does in fact violate: "will to the best of my ability, preserve, protect and defend the Constitution of the United States." That congress is allowed to disagree with verified facts should not be allowed.

@polcott Violating the oath of office is not something for which there is any legal penalty.
